I am seeing images and words coming through some images, like someone has layered over messages in a photo
I have images that I can see words and what looks like parts of other photos coming through some photos. It's like someone layered over some photos to hide messages or other photos with layers. Is there a way to breakdown the layers of a photo to see the edits or original photo


Is there a way to breakdown the layers of a photo?

The answer is mostly no, but sometimes yes. It depends on what kind of image you have: what format it is in, what software was used, and how it was edited.
If you have an image such as jpg or png, i.e. the kind that are used on the web, then these are flattened images. They don't support layers.  With these formats, getting the original layers back is impossible.
You'd need access to the original image, or a layered file, such as a psd (Photoshop), xcf (GIMP), ora (Krita), afphoto (Affinity photo), tif (specifically a layered tif), etc, in order to see the edits or the original image, or find out how it was constructed. Even then, some editing can be destructive and layers and originals might not actually be preserved even in these formats.  It would depend on the software used and what processes were used to edit the image.
